# Cosmos DB SQL API Node.js - Continuation Token

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am using the following code to get the list of documents using pagination. The code is working fine. But how do I find the continuation token if I want to send it from the client for pagination.

```
function queryCollectionPaging() {  
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    function executeNextWithRetry(iterator, callback) {         
        iterator.executeNext(function (err, results, responseHeaders) {
            if (err) {
                return callback(err, null);
            }
            else {
                documents = documents.concat(results);
                if (iterator.hasMoreResults()) {
                    executeNextWithRetry(iterator, callback);
                }
                else {
                    callback();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    let options = {
        maxItemCount: 1,
        enableCrossPartitionQuery: true
    };

    let documents = []
    let iterator = client.queryDocuments( collectionUrl, 'SELECT r.partitionkey, r.documentid, r._ts FROM root r WHERE r.partitionkey in ("user1", "user2") ORDER BY r._ts', options);

    executeNextWithRetry(iterator, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            reject(err)
        }
        else {
            console.log(documents);
            resolve(documents)
        }
    });
});
```

};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could find the continuation token in the responseHeaders parameter, please try to use `responseHeaders ['x-ms-continuation']` to grab it.

Such as :

```
continuationToken = responseHeaders ['x-ms-continuation'];
```

Then you could pass the token as a parameter to the execute method.

```
let options = {
        maxItemCount: 1,
        enableCrossPartitionQuery: true,
        continuation : continuationToken
    };
```

If the `continuationToken` is null, it means no more results.

You could refer to my previous case: [How to get & set Cosmos Db continuation token in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52149664/how-to-get-set-cosmos-db-continuation-token-in-javascript/52160454#52160454).